# What is the meaning of 凝聚人心？

Tags: meaning

This text discusses 众筹， especially relating to a group of people buying houses.

用发起人的话说，众筹不是在筹房子，而是在凝聚人心。

2 questions really:

1. In 众筹不是在筹房子, the second ‘筹’, on its own, '筹' means what? Planning? Collecting? Finding?
2. ‘凝聚人心’的意思是什么？ ‘bringing people together'?

Comment: 众筹: crowdfunding, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdfunding.

Answer (score 3):

众筹 --

众 means many people; crowd;

筹 means plan and prepare;

众筹 in the context means plan and gathering money from many people to buy a house.

‘凝聚人心’的意思是什么？ Bring the people's hearts together, so they can act as one unit and contribute together.

发起人initiator is trying to emphasize that more important thing than gathering money to buy a house is to bring the people's hearts together by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

众: crowd, multitude
筹: to raise/collect (funds)
众筹: crowdfunding, crowd financing

凝: congeal
聚: gather
凝聚: agglomerate, cohere
凝聚人心: to cohere the people

In the words of the sponsor/founder, crowdfunding is not funding for house, but cohering public feeling/mind.

Answer (score -1):

众筹：crowdfunding like Kickstarter
凝聚人心：将人们团结起来， bring people together